# Title in CollapsingToolbarLayout truncates on SearchView open

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-search

Whenever I open a `SearchView` within a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, the page title gets squashed and truncated to 1 side for some reason rather than being positioned underneath the `SearchView` widget. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

[image]

[image]

**Main layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/collapsing_toolbar" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:contentDescription="@string/string_search"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Collapsing toolbar layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myAppBarLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/myCollapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:maxLines="3">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CollapsingToolbarLayout was covered by your RecyclerView, try to change the **Main layout**